# Issue on fadeOut complete fadeIn blinking tabs elements

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Run below code snippet, you will notice the on `fadeOut` complete I have fadeIn the relative div. The div is blinking other than first I have tried to change the timings or 'fast', 'slow' the transitions also. Not worked for me.

Please provide best fit to do this kind in minimal code logic.

```js
$(document).on("click", ".action a", function (event) {
    let dataSlide = $(this).attr("data-slide");
    $(".slider .slide .slides").fadeOut(0, function () {
        $(".data-slide-" + dataSlide).fadeIn();
    });
});
```

```css
.slides {
    display: none;
}
.data-slide-1{
    display: block;
}
a{
  background:#ccc;
  padding:4px 6px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="action">
    <a data-slide="1">1</a>
    <a data-slide="2">2</a>
    <a data-slide="3">3</a>
</div>
<div class="slider">
    <div class="slide">
        <div class="slides data-slide-1">
            <h1>Slide 1</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="slides data-slide-2">
            <h1>Slide 2</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="slides data-slide-3">
            <h1>Slide 3</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is described here:

> http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/
>
> **complete**
> A function to call once the animation is complete, called once per matched element.

Because your `.fadeOut` is called on all 3 elements, each gets its own callback and because only 1 is visible, the others area already hidden so the .fadeIn is called immediately (hence appearing to run at the same time) twice and then a third time for the visible element.

You can confirm this by adding a console.log inside the callback:

```
$(".slider .slide .slides").fadeOut(0, function () {
    $(".data-slide-" + dataSlide).fadeIn();
    console.log($(this).text())
});
```

My solution would be to track the "active" element, only hide that and then you only get one callback.

```js
$(document).on("click", ".action a", function(event) {
  let dataSlide = $(this).attr("data-slide");
  $(".slide.active")
    .removeClass("active")
    .fadeOut(500, function() {
      $(".data-slide-" + dataSlide)
        .addClass("active")
        .fadeIn(500);
    })
});
$(".slide.data-slide-1").addClass("active").show();
```

```css
.slide {
  display: none;
}

a {
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 4px 6px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="action">
  <a data-slide="1">1</a>
  <a data-slide="2">2</a>
  <a data-slide="3">3</a>
</div>
<div class="slider">
  <div class="slides">
    <div class="slide data-slide-1">
      <h1>Slide 1</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="slide data-slide-2">
      <h1>Slide 2</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="slide data-slide-3">
      <h1>Slide 3</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Absolutely fabulous @freedomn-m. It's exactly what I imagined. Thanks for exact resolution.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** The issue is that it's per element not just the visible one, and the non-visible ones complete immediately.

Use `siblings()` to make sure only one animation on one element at same time.

```js
$(document).on("click", ".action a", function(event) {
  let slide = $(".data-slide-" + $(this).attr("data-slide"))
  slide.siblings().fadeOut(0, function() {
    slide.fadeIn();
  });
});
```

```css
.slides {
  display: none;
}

.data-slide-1 {
  display: block;
}

a {
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 4px 6px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="action">
  <a data-slide="1">1</a>
  <a data-slide="2">2</a>
  <a data-slide="3">3</a>
</div>
<div class="slider">
  <div class="slide">
    <div class="slides data-slide-1">
      <h1>Slide 1</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="slides data-slide-2">
      <h1>Slide 2</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="slides data-slide-3">
      <h1>Slide 3</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes right works fine but when we tried to click quickly then it's shown two elements for some times, because `setTimeout` will executes after a time specified. It's actually lagging after so many clicks simultaneously. 
So that's why I used `fadeOut` `complete` event.

Comment: It's not because they "work at the same time" - this is misleading.  The fadeIn in the callback only runs when the fadeOut has completed - the issue is that it's *per element* not just the visible one, and the non-visible ones complete immediately.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.promise()`](https://api.jquery.com/promise/) i.e once the `fadeout` finishes you call `fadein`, The `.promise()` method returns a dynamically generated Promise that is resolved once all actions in previous chain are ended.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(document).on("click", ".action a", function (event) {
    let slide = $(".data-slide-" + $(this).attr("data-slide"));
    slide.siblings().fadeOut(0).promise().done(function () {
      slide.fadeIn();
    });
  });
});
```

here's the fiddle:
https://codepen.io/nitinjs-the-typescripter/pen/XWxbOyW